# Getting "Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." when trying to call a Node Module : Gulp enviroment

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

So I'm a big fan of webpack but I have to use only gulp in this work I'm doing and I'm living a nightmare configuring this to actually start working.

On my **index.js** there is just `import Swiper from 'swiper'` And this error returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "swiper". 
Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I'm using this configuration in my **gulpfile** :

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create()

const paths = {
  html: {
    src: ['./src/**/*.html'],
    dest: './dist/',
  },
  images: {
    src: ['./src/images/**/*'],
    dest: './dist/content/images/',
  },
  styles: {
    src: ['./src/scss/**/*.scss'],
    dest: './dist/css/',
  },
  scripts: {
    src: ['./src/scripts/**/*.js'],
    dest: './dist/js/',
  },
  cachebust: {
    src: ['./dist/**/*.html'],
    dest: './dist/',
  },
};

function copyHtml() {
  return src(paths.html.src).pipe(dest(paths.html.dest)).pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function optimizeImages() {
  return src(paths.images.src)
    .pipe(imagemin().on('error', (error) => console.log(error)))
    .pipe(dest(paths.images.dest))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function compileStyles() {
  return src(paths.styles.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(dest('./src/css/'))
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(dest(paths.styles.dest))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function minifyScripts() {
  return src(paths.scripts.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(terser().on('error', (error) => console.log(error)))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(dest(paths.scripts.dest))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function cacheBust() {
  return src(paths.cachebust.src)
    .pipe(replace(/cache_bust=\d+/g, 'cache_bust=' + new Date().getTime()))
    .pipe(dest(paths.cachebust.dest));
}

function browserSync() {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './src'
    }
  })
}

function watcher() {
  watch(paths.html.src, series(copyHtml, cacheBust));
  watch(paths.images.src, optimizeImages);
  watch(paths.styles.src, parallel(compileStyles, cacheBust));
  watch(paths.scripts.src, parallel(minifyScripts, cacheBust));
}

exports.copyHtml = copyHtml;
exports.optimizeImages = optimizeImages;
exports.compileStyles = compileStyles;
exports.minifyScripts = minifyScripts;
exports.cacheBust = cacheBust;
exports.watcher = watcher;

exports.default = series(
  parallel(copyHtml, optimizeImages, compileStyles, minifyScripts),
  cacheBust,
  parallel(watcher, browserSync)
);
```

My **index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend-challenge-heflerdev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Pontos importantes antes de iniciar",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/HeflerDev/frontend-challenge-junior.git"
  },
  "author": "HeflerDev",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/HeflerDev/frontend-challenge-junior/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/HeflerDev/frontend-challenge-junior#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "cssnano": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.1.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-terser": "^2.1.0",
    "node": "^17.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.8",
    "sass": "^1.49.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "swiper": "^8.0.7"
  }
}
```

**EDIT** 
**Some of the folder structure**

```
|dist/
|src/
    |scripts
        |index.js
    |css
    |scss
    |images
    |index.html
```

I tried a lot of things and I'm just banging my head on the wall, could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show the actual source file where you're importing swiper, I will assume that it's inside of this file on the client:

```
<script type="module" src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
```

From client-side JS files, you can't just do:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper'
```

As the error message from the browser says, you have to specify some type of path and you have to make sure your server is then serving the `swiper` module from that path.

Probably you want to do something like:

```
import Swiper from '/scripts/swiper'
```

since you rarely want to use relative paths for serving files on the client.  And, then you also have to configure your server to respond to the request for `/scripts/swiper` to serve the swiper module.

Remember that a nodejs web server does not serve ANY files by default.  You have to configure it to serve any file you want to server back to the client.  You can often use something like `express.static()` to serve a whole directory or directory hierarchy of files with one statement, but you have to configure that properly.

Comment: Oh, you have a good point, I will setup express here and post any update.